# mysqli_fetch_array with only one element

Tags: php, mysqli

I always used to put db elements into an array with a `while loop`.
Reading the documentation I saw other ways to put elements into an array, but when I tried to use those system, I always got an empty array.

E.g. in this case where is my error?

This works:

```
$data_db = $link->query("SELECT Name FROM TEST_TABLE");
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($data_db)){
    $names[] = $data['Name'];
}

foreach($names as $n){
    echo $n;
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
$data_db = $link->query("SELECT Name FROM TEST_TABLE");
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($data_db);

foreach($data['Name'] as $d){
    echo $d;
}
```

Comment: You should say *thank you* with an *accepted* answer if any of the answers have sufficed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be because in the second example, when you call `$data = mysqli_fetch_array($data_db);`, that fetches *a single row*. So, you're essentially trying to iterate over `$data['Name']`, which makes no real sense. Note that the `while` loop means that on each iteration the statement will be executed, but in the second example you're only executing the `$data = mysqli_fetch_array($data_db)` once.

Answer (score 4):

`mysqli_fetch_*()` functions return a single **ROW** of data. they do not return the entire result set. `$data['Name']` is going to be a single **STRING**, which you're trying to loop over as an array, hence getting nothing but nulls.

Comment: Thank you! So the only way to have an array of results, is to use the `while` loop?

Comment: some libraries have a variant of `fetchAll()` type logic, which do return the entire set. But internally they'll just be doing a while loop and building the array for you.

Comment: Also, it is possible to use other methods, but you'd have to build some sort of other API. For example, some libraries implement the [Iterator interface](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) to support iterating over results in a `foreach` loop, but in simple terms, the `while` loop is a fine solution.